# How do i read a file line by line in javaFx using a button with mouse event

Tags: javafx

When i press this button, its supposed to read the next line of a file, every time i press it. why is it not working with this code.

```
btnFrw.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file); //read 'file'
        br = new BufferedReader(fr); //read 'file'
        String line = "";
        while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
            line = br.readLine();

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
            txtID.setText(st.nextToken());
            txtG.setText(st.nextToken());
            txtBP.setText(st.nextToken());
            txtD.setText(st.nextToken());
            txtCons.setText(st.nextToken());
            txtSP.setText(st.nextToken());
        }
    } catch(Exception k) {
        System.out.println("Reading file.");
    }
});
```

ok so I figured it out to include a while loop. But that still doesnt do what i need. In one click it will read through all the lines and set the text areas to the current line. What i need is for it to move to a new line each time the buttons is clicked and set the text areas to that line using String tokenizer.

Comment: Is it a large file so you don't want to read the whole thing at once?  Probably not or clicking wouldn't be fun.  I suggest reading the whole file into a list and showing it line by line on clicks.  You need to close the file somewhere, and you're re-opening it every time.  You have some errors but it's tedious to do your way.

Comment: it's not a large file. What list should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using String to read line you can use an array of string to store each line separately and then show them on button click. Here's the code

```
String[] lineList = null;


        try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);//read 'file'
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);//read 'file'
        String line = "";

        int lines = 0;
        while (br.readLine() != null) {
            lines++;
        }
        lineList = new String[lines];
        int i = 0;
        while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
            lineList[i] = br.readLine();
            i++;
        }

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            int loop = 0;

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println(lineList[loop]);
                loop++;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Netbeans says the loop variable must be final. So this code doesnt work.

Comment: declare the loop variable inside the button event handler outside handle method. At that point it wont say it to declare as final. It worked when i tried.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to read them into a list, then you can even use `Files.readAll`.

```
    final List<String> lines;
    try {
         lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
    } catch (IOException ex) { 
        return;
    }
    //need final object since we use it in lambda
    final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Button btnFrw = new Button("clk me");
    btnFrw.setOnAction(e ->{
        if (i.get() < lines.size())
            System.out.println(i.get()+" "+lines.get(i.getAndIncrement()));
        else 
            System.out.println("No more lines");
    });
```